# move from callback to suspend function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I have this function :

```
fun createBiometricPrompt(
        activity: AppCompatActivity,
        processSuccess: (BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) -> Unit,
        callback: BiometricCallback
    ): BiometricPrompt {
        var nbFailure = 0
        val executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity)

        val callback = object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {

            override fun onAuthenticationError(errCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errCode, errString)
                Log.d(TAG, "errCode is $errCode and errString is: $errString")
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                Log.d(TAG, "User biometric rejected.")
                nbFailure++;
                if(nbFailure == MAX_BIOMETRICS_FAILURE){
                    nbFailure = 0
                    callback.onFailure()
                }
            }
```

which is using a callback `callback: BiometricCallback`, it's only for now using it for notifying that a failure happened by sending `callback.onFailure()`

Callback is called in the calling Fragment by doing this:

Fragment.kt

```
biometricPrompt =
                BiometricPromptUtils.createBiometricPrompt(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity, ::encryptAndStoreServerToken, object: BiometricCallback {
                    override fun onFailure() {
                        biometricPrompt.cancelAuthentication()
                        viewModel.loginError.set("Error Biometrics")
                    }
                })
```

The `onFailure` is used then to cancel the process and display an error.

The Callback interface is defined as :

```
interface BiometricCallback {
    fun onFailure()
}
```

I have been asked to use a suspend function instead of a callback but I have no clue how to do it properly. Should I use LiveData ? If any idea, please help

Thanks

Comment: What do you want the function to actually do? Creating a prompt is a synchronous, non-blocking task so it doesn’t need to be a suspend function. But waiting for the results of the prompt could be a suspend function that returns successful authentication or failure. In that case, you would have to create the prompt, show it, and return the result all inside the suspend function without the caller ever touching the BiometricPrompt class.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` or `suspendCoroutine` to convert any callback based Api in direct style to make it more kotlin friendly plus it provides more encapsulation you will be just returned with the result all complexity is handled inside the function only

```
 suspend fun authenticate():BiomatricPrompt.AuthenticationResult? {
 return suspendCancelableCoroutine { continuation -> 
     biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(this, executor,
        object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
    override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int,
            errString: CharSequence) {
        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
        continuation.resume(null,null)
    }

    override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(
            result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
         continuation.resume(result,null)
    }

    override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
        super.onAuthenticationFailed()
         continuation.resume(null,null)
    }
   })
    promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
        .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
        .setNegativeButtonText("Use account password")
        .build()
    biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
 }
}
```

usage

```
val authenticationResult  = authenticate()
if(authenticationResult == null){
 //authentication failed
}else{
//authenticated successfully 
}
```

you can use custom object as result type to handle more use cases

[more information](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/suspending-over-views-19de9ebd7020)